# How to get Android app reviewing approval quicker

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I'm going to publish an app to Play Store, but it has been under In Review for more than 2 weeks,
I fixed all warning message but still no any update from Google,

I pushed some update for fixing some warning of the app , and increase version number, but they all are being under In-Review,
I also have some version for open-testing, they are also in-review

[image]

[image]

What should I do to get approval from Google soon

Comment: On average of app approval takes around 2-4 days, but sometimes it will be greater or lesser, for me 3 hours was lowest and 8 days was highest for app approval. In your case as you already said, it was around 2 weeks, Get a Google Play Console support, contact them and write a mail, as it could help you https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/gethelp?sjid=14940164685001365182-AP

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that, I've tried everything